# appcompat-v7:27.0.1 Issue with play-services-maps

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have this gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.estimote:sdk:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'

}
```

I have problem with appcompat-v7:27.0.1 and the google play services.
if I use the 26.0.1 there is not problem with the google play services but cant use the afollestand 0.9.5.0.
I need the afollestand 0.9.5.0 that works with appcompat-v7:27

UPDATE:
[Gradle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwSXr.png)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I need the afollestand  0.9.5.0 for that I need appcompact v7 27.0.1 but with that the google dont work

Comment: why will it not work? any error?

Comment: appcomat error is that other are ussing other version when I delete the maps compile the error disapier

Comment: i do not understand your problem It should work fine.

Comment: it should but if you try it 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
makes a conflict with

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'

Comment: i tried and i see no conflict

Comment: I edit with the image of the gradle with the error

Comment: you should read this https://blog.mindorks.com/avoiding-conflicts-in-android-gradle-dependencies-28e4200ca235. Just make sure all libs use the same version. How do you find out? run ./gradlew app:dependencies on linux and on windows gradlew.bat app:dependencies on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try Everything, but the real answer was wait to and update of play-services.
now my gradle looks like:

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.YYY"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

And have 0 errors.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem. What user raghunandan suggested helps.

Using `./gradlew app:dependencies` in your Apps folder ( or `./gradlew.bat app:dependencies` on Windows), you get the dependency tree of all the packages.

There you can see that 'play-services-maps' requires some support packages with version `25.2.0`, but most of them get **upgraded** to 27.0.2. But not all for some reason. You can do this manually though, by including them directly! (They will be part of your APK anyway)

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```

add that in your apps build.gradle alongside support-v7 and it'll work.

Comment: I add that compile line but get a error  of mixing versions, some library use v7:25...

Comment: Again, check with app:dependencies. Which one are listed as using 25.x? Did you include them yourself? then upgrade the version. Were they pulled in by something else? Include them manually as 27.0.2.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If no, what's the wrong, if yes, please accept this answer.

Comment: I haven't Worked yet on the project, but the last time I check i guess the one using 25.x its the maps services